# Keep Excel from inserting "@" into formula

Tags: excel, vba

I feel like I'm missing something basic, but I have the following bit of code that is referring to a table on another sheet.

```
Sub availabilityTab()
Dim cell As String
Dim i As Integer

With Sheets("Availability")
.Cells.Clear
.Range("A3") = "=BackgroundData[#Headers]"

    For i = 1 To 5
    cell = .Cells(3, i)
    .Cells(4, i) = "=BackgroundData[" & cell & "]"
    Next i


End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, when it inserts the formula in these cells it inserts an "@" that keeps the result from spilling, such as

```
=@BackgroundData[#Headers]
```

in A3. Or

```
=BackgroundData[@ID]
```

in A4. How do I keep it from inserting the @?
Thanks!

Comment: `BackgroundData[ID]` without the `@` symbol is a reference to a column, not a cell. Is that what you're trying to get?

Comment: @jsheeran yes I want the column to spill down. Same with the Headers row: I want it to spill.